# Invalid use of group function in Lag Function

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, window-functions

I am brand new to SQL and have a fairly simple query but I keep getting the error "Invalid use of group function" when trying to use it. Here is my query:

```
select CreateDate as date,
 count(*) as count,
 lag(count(*), 1) OVER (order by CreateDate) as Previous 
from contacts
```

Can someone explain why this would not work and how I can get it to function properly?

Answer (score 3):

Your query raises error message:

> `ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS`: In aggregated query without `GROUP BY`, expression #1 of `SELECT` list contains nonaggregated column 'test.contacts.createdate'; this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

This has nothing to do with `lag()`. Your query is just missing a `group by` clause:

```
select 
    CreateDate as date,
    count(*) as count,
    lag(count(*), 1) over(order by CreateDate) as previous 
from contacts
group by createdate
```